# JavaScript Memory Leak. An object is not removed because of function variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-devtools

I have created an object `this.bookView = new BookView();`

The Garbage Collector is not removing the object when I do `this.bookView=null`.

Google Dev Tool Profile Snapshot Retainers window shows below connections (which shows that something has reference to the object).

[image]

All rows are `"Preview is not available"` except `context in ()`.

[image]

[image]

The problem is `BookView` has `addSheet` function variable which hasn't used anywhere (yet), but holds a ref to itself through `_this`.

**What I tried:**

1) `this.bookView.addSheet = null;` (didn't help)

2) `delete this.bookView.addSheet;` (didn't help)

**My questions:**

1) How to remove this connection from the Window and make `bookView` to be garbage collected?

2) Why the `addSheet` variable is linked from Window object?

3) What are the `transitions` and `descriptors` on the `retainers` window?

4) What other tools I can use to find more details about this kind of memory leak.

P.S. The `bookView` object is created inside a Durandal page. `this.bookView` is basically a `page1.bookView`. The page is removed correctly. During the `deactivate` (page removal) function I call `this.bookView = null;`

Comment: `addSheet` or `AddSheet`?

Comment: Typo, fixed. `addSheet`. Thanks

Comment: If you've paused the debugger and some of the relevant variables are shown in panels or console, the devtools debugger itself may retain the references.

Comment: Try using `this` instead of `_this`. Anyways, you should post your code. See [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not instantiating `BookView` from within a `function`, `this` will be your `window` object, which is global. You have attached it globally to the one object that will live until you close you browser or tab. You can try to get rid of `BookView` by trying `delete window['bookView']`

EDIT: In your Durandal page deactivate callback, run through your `this` and delete its keys.

```
for(var key in this)
   delete this[key];
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't write about it - the bookView is created inside a Durandal page. The Durandal page is removed correctly. During the page's deactivate (page removal) function I call `this.bookView = null;`. I'll edit original post

Comment: What prints out when you do a `console.log(window.bookView)`?

Comment: `console.log(window.bookView)` prints `undefined`

Comment: In your Durandal page deactivate callback, run through your this and delete its keys `for(var key in this) delete this[key];`